# Site root: Github Pages vs. `jekyll --server`

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

When I run `jekyll --server` my site is available at `http://localhost:4000/`, but when I deploy to GitHub Project Pages, it's available at `http://username.github.com/projectname/`.

This means that I cannot use absolute URLs when referring to stylesheets and other resources. Relative URLs break when the same layout is used by e.g. `index.html` and `2012/01/01/happy-new-year.html`. What is the-accepted/a-good way of adding stylesheets and other resources to a GitHub Project Pages repository?

*Cross-posted to [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/760).*

Comment: Use relative URLs instead?

Comment: Relative URLs break if e.g. the same layout is used by /index.html and /2012/01/01/happy-new-year/.

Comment: If you have an *assets* directory in the root of your project, `/assets/whatever.js` will work from anywhere. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 29):

This problem arises because the root directory is always the user url (user.github.com), in both user and project pages. I found a solution to this: Configure the `url` variable in the `_config.yml` file to the github project page:

```
safe: true
...
url: "http://user.github.io/project-name"
```

then, in the layouts, use absolute references, using the `site.url` variable to do that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.url }}/css/styles.css">
```

and run the server using:

```
$jekyll --server --url=http://localhost:4000
```

The command line option overwrite the setting in the configuration file in local mode. With those settings, I get all the links pointing to the right place, both hosted in github and    in local mode.

---

**UPDATE: Jekyll 1.0** Since Jekyll reached 1.0, the aforemetioned options `server` and `url` and its respective command line options `--server` and `--url` have been deprecated. Instructions for the new version:

In the `_config.yml` file, add the variable `baseurl` (without trailing slash):

```
baseurl: "http://user.github.io/project-name"
```

In the layouts or pages, use absolute references, using the `site.baseurl` variable:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/styles.css">
```

and then, run the local server (the baseurl option is empty on purpose):

```
$ jekyll serve --watch --baseurl=
```

More details about the changes in the [docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/).

Comment: this `--url` is deprecated. I do тещ know how to solve. Have the same issue.

Comment: It disables custom plugins. If you use github pages, all the plugins will be disabled.

Comment: Although this might work, I think the intended way to use the --baseurl option is actually like @SergeyRomanov [described it in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16509937/5039).

Comment: In both answers the option is used in the same way, to specify the base url of the project. This question is about how to handle the use of github pages for project pages both in local and in github.

Answer (score 4):

Since `--url` in command line has been deprecated there is another solution.

Let's say your URL path is `repo` in you `http://name.github.io/repo`. Now in all links use absolute URLs like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/repo/css/syntax.css">
```

Or links

```
<a href="/repo/license/">License</a>
```

All you need now is to add `--baseurl` to command line when you run it locally.

```
jekyll --server --baseurl /repo/
```

Comment: I couldn't find the deprecation of the `url` command line option in the docs, but I think that this solution is better. Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: You can see that in docs about [configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) `--url` even not mentioned.

Comment: lifesaver. I've been headdesking all morning and your answer is the only thing that has worked. There needs to be more documentation/simple examples for getting up and running with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of jekyll (1.1.2) I found it's best to create a separate configuration file from the original. The only difference? The url (or baseurl variable).

The default _config.yml has:

```
url: myurl.com
```

The new config (lets call it _preview_config.yml):

```
url: localhost:4000
```

This will reassign all your absolute links depending on what configuration you use. Now to run the server with the preview config use:

```
jekyll serve -w --config _preview_config.yml
```

A full explanation is on my [blog](http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/jekyll-local-preview/).

Comment: +1, except if you use `jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_preview_config.yml` you can keep your other settings. In this case, _preview_config.yml only contains the url line.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in short: add `baseurl: '/project-name'` in `_config.yml`

For CSS/JS links: `{{ site.baseurl }}/css/styles.css`

For all other links: `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}`

The official Jeykll GH-Pages answer is here: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/

#### Excerpt:

### Project Page URL Structure

Sometimes it’s nice to preview your Jekyll site before you push your `gh-pages` branch to GitHub. However, the subdirectory-like URL structure GitHub uses for Project Pages complicates the proper resolution of URLs. Here is an approach to utilizing the GitHub Project Page URL structure (`username.github.io/project-name/`) whilst maintaining the ability to preview your Jekyll site locally.

1. In `_config.ym`l, set the `baseurl` option to `/project-name` – note the leading slash and the absence of a trailing slash. ex: `baseurl: '/my-proj'`
2. When referencing JS or CSS files, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl}}/path/to/css.css` – note the slash immediately following the variable (just before “path”).
3. When doing permalinks or internal links, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}` – note that there is no slash between the two variables.
4. Finally, if you'd like to preview your site before committing/deploying using `jekyll serve`, be sure to pass an empty string to the `--baseurl` option, so that you can view everything at `localhost:4000` normally (without `/project-name` at the beginning): ex: `jekyll serve --baseurl ''`

This way you can preview your site locally from the site root on localhost, but when GitHub generates your pages from the gh-pages branch all the URLs will start with `/project-name` and resolve properly.

Answer (score 0):

I use jekyll-bootstrap and deploy locally on port 4000, but my github pages url is user.github.com...i think that it depends on how you originally create the repo.  Originally I used the auto page builder that github offers which created the repo in a very wizard like manner.

I just followed the steps at:

http://jekyllbootstrap.com/

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm talking about GitHub Project Pages, not GitHub User Pages.